# Jquery - Mouseover DIV = addClass

Tags: jquery

i build this really simple script but i did not work.

Can somebody tell me where the bug is?

**HTML**

```
<div id="hello" style="border: 1px solid #000000; margin:10px; padding:5px;">Hello</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid #000000; margin:10px; padding:5px;">Word</div>
<div style="margin:10px; padding:5px;">Test</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function()
{

    $('div').live('hover', function (event)
    {
             if (event.type == 'mouseover')
             {
               $(this).addClass('mark');
             }
             else
             {
               $(this).removeClass('mark');
             }
    });

});
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/4pYth/4/

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use two separate live events for this one.

```
$('div').live('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).addClass('mark');
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('mark');
)};
```

Edit:

Here is a link for the differences between `mouseenter` and `mouseover`, just in case you are curious:
[What is the difference between the mouseover and mouseenter events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)

Comment: I think your jsfiddle was using mootools and not jquery. http://www.jsfiddle.net/4pYth/12/

Answer (score 0):

`hover` is not an event.

Many of the event-related shortcut methods on jQuery objects are actual events: `click`, `submit`, etc. But `hover` is not, it's a separate shortcut method that registers a `mouseenter` and a `mouseleave` event.

`live()` can only accept events, so if you want to use hover-like code with it you'll need separate events, as in Kyle's example.

However, this will be a little bit slow because now jQuery has to monitor every mouse movement to see if it is happening to/from a `div` element. It may be faster to just use `hover()` to bind the `mouseenter`/`leave` events on divs currently in the page, without `live`-ness. If you do have dynamically-added `div` elements that would mean having to rebind when adding them to the document though.

Better: just use CSS hover. It's only IE6 where good old `:hover` fails; if you really need to provide nice hover effects to users of that browser (bah! they don't deserve it, the scoundrels!) then you can add fallback script for that browser only, eg.:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div:hover, div.hover { background: red; }
</style>

<!--[if lt IE 7]><body class="browser-ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--><body><!--<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($(document.body).hasClass('browser-ie6')) {
        $('div').live('mouseenter', function() {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        }).live('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        )};
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using this method for browser detection and no the jQuery $.browser checks?

Comment: As the jQuery source says, “Use of jQuery.browser is frowned upon”. It's a crude `navigator.userAgent` string search that can go wrong for *many* reasons, but especially in false positives for IE, since many other clients have had the string `msie` in their User-Agent strings at various points. Conditional comments are a *much* more accurate method when the browser you need to isolate is IE. They're not as good as feature-sniffing (`$.support` in jQuery), but you can't reasonably feature-sniff hover support. A class on the `body` also makes it easy to serve IE-only stylesheet rules.