# jquery mouseenter mouse leave

Tags: .net, jquery

I am having trouble getting the moues enter mouse leave functionality work. I know there is a .hover option I can take, I want to get the mouseenter/mouseleave working before i go up to that.

What i am seeing is, I have chrome opened up and am inspecting the img, it says that the src file is changing but i am not seeing a noticable change. Can someone help please

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>

            <img id="menuHome" src="m_home.gif" />
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#menuHome").mouseenter(function() {
                            $(this).attr({ src: 'm_home_roll.gif' });
                        });
                        $("#menuHome").mouseleave(function() {
                            $(this).attr({ src: 'm_home.gif' });
                        });
                    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does chrome sent a http request to load the image? And are you sure the images are different?

Comment: 100% sure images are different, on the resources tab after the initial rollover chrome does request the m_home_roll.gif

Comment: THe first time i Rollover the image it changes, but subsequent times it doesn't. If i refresh the page i can get the image to change but again, subsequent times it will not change.

Comment: it works just fine in IE and FireFox

Comment: Might it be possible that these events are getting cleared out when you change the source? Just for sanity sake, try rebinding the events after the src is loaded.

Comment: Pretty new to jquery here, how would i go about rebinding after the source changes?

Comment: the same thing happens when I try to use the hover event. It works the first time in chrome, but no other time. And it works perfectly in ie and firefox. Code below


                    $("#menuHome").hover(
                        function() {
                        $(this).attr({ src: 'm_home_roll.gif' });
                            }
                         ,function(){
                            $(this).attr({ src: 'm_home.gif' });
                            
                        });
                    });

Comment: From what I can tell from your code, it looks like your trying to do a simple image rollover. You should consider using CSS sprites for this as it is a) faster and b) works with javascript disabled.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Comment: I chose not do a sprite because i wanted to play with jquery. I assume i can go and plug a css sprite in and that would work, but i am really curious as to why this itself isnt working. Does anyone else have this problem with the code above?

Comment: Yes! Using Chrome, this has happened to me as well. But, I still have no idea why. I hear Chrome has some pretty annoying cache issues for developers. Hopefully someone will have a solution.

Comment: Actually when you say the first time you roll over it changes. Does that mean first time you enter it changes AND leave it changes back or just first enter?

Comment: Since it looks like nobody can reproduce this behaviour, is it possible to provide a working demonstration of this bug?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Chrome I think, I seem to remember using `mouseover` and `mouseout` instead. So something like this:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $('#menuHome')
        .mouseover(function() {
            $(this).attr({src: 'm_home_roll.gif'});
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            $(this).attr({src: 'm_home.gif'});
        });
});
```

There is also no need to select the element twice (hence the single `$('#menuHome')` line).

Comment: Yes, it looks to me like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` may be specific to Internet Explorer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the reason but could you try this with slightly different syntax?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menuHome").hover(function() {
        this.src = 'm_home_roll.gif';
    }, function() {
        this.src = 'm_home.gif';
    });
});
```

Comment: tried with the different syntax and didnt help. I like this sytanx better. Why did you not have to include the      $(this)    ?

Comment: @george9170 Inside a handler function, `this` refers to the DOM element. You can perform jQuery actions on it by wrapping it in `$()`, but you can access normal Javascript element methods and properties on `this`.  This will always have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain the uri of those images is correct AND that you're waiting an appropriate amount of time to load them when you roll over / roll off (the first time, usually they cache after that) then switch `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).load()` and see if it works better?

Comment: $(window).load()seems to have the same behavior
      $(window).load(
                   function() {
                       $("#menuHome").hover(function() {
                           this.src = 'm_home_roll.gif';
                       }, function() {
                           this.src = 'm_home.gif';
                       });
                   });

anyone else having this issue with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has explored this, I'll venture a guess. As I commented to the OP, it might have something to do with the events getting unbind after you change source. To verify this, you can put a break point or put an alert statement in both events. Whenever you rollover and there's no alert popping up, that means your events are getting unbound somehow.

Given that, try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menuHome").live('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).attr({ src: 'm_home_roll.gif' });
    });
    $("#menuHome").live('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).attr({ src: 'm_home.gif' });
    });
});
```

to see if it's readding the element to the DOM. If that doesn't work, try:

```
function enter() {
    $(this).attr({ src: 'm_home_roll.gif' });
    readd();
}
function leave() {
    $(this).attr({ src: 'm_home.gif' })
    readd();
}

// can't refer to function handler while inside function
function readd(elem) {
    $('#menuHome').unbind().mousenter(enter).mouseleave(leave);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menuHome").mouseenter(enter).mouseleave(leave);
});
```

Comment: A nicer way to test this would be using `delegate`: $(document.body).delegate('#menuHome', 'mouseenter', function(){this.src='m_home_roll.gif';}).delegate('#menuHome', 'mouseleave', function(){this.src='m_home.gif';});`

Comment: lol I had to look up the difference of live and delegate. I believe that they are both valid here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are open to a code structure change, but I would code something like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){`
    $('#rolloverImg').html("<img src=\"...\">");`

    $('#rolloverImg').hover(function(event){
       $(this).html("<img src=\"...new src...\">");
    }, function(event){
       $(this).html("<img src=\"...old src...\">");
    });
});
</script>

....
<div id="rolloverImg"></div>
```