# How to properly make jQuery hover work

Tags: jquery

I have this test page: http://www.problemio.com/index_new.php

and I am trying to make some jQuery for hovering functionality.  But I am not exactly sure how to  go about it.  Have some jQuery code like this:

```
$('ul#environment li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first-child').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first-child').hide();
});

$('ul#health li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first-child').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first-child').hide();
});
```

and HTML on the page like this:

```
        <div style="display:none;">
            <ul id="environment" >
                <li>Green Lifestyle</li>
                <li>Energy Use</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="health">
                <li>Medicine</li>
                <li>Diet</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and then I have some HTML  links that I want to display the appropriate hover effect when the user mouses over.

How do I do that? I seem to have seperate pieces of the functionality, but not sure how to make it all play together.

Comment: You are trying to make a `hovering functionality`. Can you be more precise about what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Your page is currently throwing an exception: `ShowSubCategories is not defined`. The error is coming from this line: `onmouseover="ShowSubCategories(62);"`. Are you missing a JS reference?

Comment: @JamesHill got rid of the exception - thanks.

Comment: @pinouchon I am hoping for hovering on mouse-over on the different categories.

Comment: Maybe you are confused by the difference between [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/). Also take a look at this question: [Difference between mouseover and mouseenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)

Comment: Good point - I was confused - those links helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hover over something that isn't displayed.

```
<div style="display: none;">
```

Because you have `display: none;`, your menu is not visible/hoverable. Remove this, and then you can start to work from there.

Comment: good point, but I don't really want to display that menu though. How do I only make it displayable on mouse over?

Comment: If you want it visible by default that's fine, but you won't be able to mouse over it... you'll have to mouse over something else that will display your menu.

Comment: If you could describe the functionality you are trying to create, we could definitely help you get it to work. With your current post, it's a little hard to tell what you are trying to create. Do you want the whole menu to appear on hover, or just the first `<li>` element?