# In jQuery what's the best way to add a class on mouseover and remove it on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover, mouseout

Is there a jQuery shortcut for this?

```
$(element).on("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

I see in the jQuery docs a method called `hover()`, but that seems to bind on events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (should I be using those events instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Description

You can user jQuery's `hover()` method.

Check out the sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/T5aXb/1/)

#### Sample

```
$(elem).hover(function(ev) {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function(ev) {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

#### More Information

- **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/T5aXb/1/)**
- [jQuery.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Is there any reason not to use @lonesomeday's more compact form with just a toggle?

Comment: (assuming I know the initial state has no "hover" class)

Comment: Yes you said it right. The sample from lonesomeday's just switch the class, no matter if you have the class set initial or not.

Comment: Ok. @lonesomeday's answer is pretty slick and would probably work for me, but I'm going to go with the safer route.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way, to remove duplication of code, is by passing one argument to [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) and use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass):

```
$(elem).hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Will this definitely always work? Is there any way the "toggle state" might get out of sync?

Comment: you take a risk, because you don't know what was the initial state.

Comment: @BenLee Only if you are toggling it with some other bit of code, which seems quite unlikely/foolish.

Comment: @gdoron, assuming I do know the initial state. I just want to make sure there are no edge cases (like the cursor going from "over element" to "outside browser window" to "not over element" type deal).

Comment: I voted for this AND dknaack's answers -- yes, there is a risk that toggle state can go out of sync if you're not aware of or in control of your full scenario. But if you are, it's pretty slick. But on the other hand, 3 lines vs. 5 lines... you could always go the safe route with dknaack's.

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
$(element).hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`hover()` is only a bit more compact:

```
$(elem).hover(function(ev) {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
},function(ev) {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

For the difference between mouseover/mouseout and mouseenter/mouseleave, see [What is the difference between the mouseover and mouseenter events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)