# Color animation jQuery plugin: the animation triggers for both parent and child elements. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coloranimation

Only yesterday did I need to animate the border color of an HTML `div` and came across the color animation jquery plugin from [bitstorm](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/). It is lightweight and simple to use, but it seems that it has a bug. 
I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<div class="object-list-item" id="oli-0" reference="0">
    <div class="close_btn" tooltip_text="Remove this object"></div>
    <img class="thumb" src="img/text-icon.png" />
    <div class="text-preview"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

where there's some space (in pixels) between the inner elements and the border of the parent element.
Additionally, I've added two event handlers for the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events, attached to the `object-list-item` element like so:

```
$(document)
        .on("mouseover", "div.object-list-item", function(){
            $(this).animate({ borderColor : "#555" },300);                                                       
        })
        .on("mouseout", "div.object-list-item", function(){
            $(this).animate({ borderColor : "#ddd" },300);                                                       
        });
```

I also put together a fiddle where you can see this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/2UKRG/2/

The problem is that when I hover any of the inner elements, the event handler triggers for them as well. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm lazy right now but is pretty sure you just have to change `mouseover, mouseout` to `mouseenter, mouseleave`:

http://jsfiddle.net/2UKRG/3/

```
$(document)
    .on("mouseenter", "div.object-list-item", function(){
        $(this).animate({ borderColor : "#555" },300);                                                         
    })
    .on("mouseleave", "div.object-list-item", function(){
        $(this).animate({ borderColor : "#ddd" },300);                                                         
    });​
```

Comment: That's just...weird...It did fix the problem, but WHY?! It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @AndreiOniga Again lazy but you can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover

Answer (score 2):

You could also try changing it to `hover` instead - **http://jsfiddle.net/WJE2y/**

```
$('div.object-list-item').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({ borderColor : "#555" },300);
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({ borderColor : "#ddd" },300);
});
```

As for the '*why*' - the answer for [What is the difference between the mouseover and mouseenter events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events) explains it quite well and links to http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseover

Comment: OK...Both your and Andreas' suggestions seem to work (at least in Chrome), but why?! It doesn't make any sense to me and it's just horrifyingly weird to me.

Comment: Hmmm, now that that's fixed, this actually generates a new problem: When I hover the child elements, the border changes back, as if I've hovered away from the parent element. This doesn't need to happen, the border should remain dark until the user leaves the parent element altogether, but not sooner than that. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Both the fiddle in the answer and my one don't fade the border until you hover out of the parent. Have I missed something?

Comment: Indeed, but I need to use the `on()` method in order to bind the handler to newly added elements. How do I get around the current problem by using `on()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover - apparently not :(

Comment: Ah, never mind. It was my mistake, I didn't realize I hadn't swapped `mouseout` with `mouseleave`, so I was using this combination: `$(document).on("mouseenter", "div.object-list-item", function(){}).on("mouseout", "div.object-list-item", function(){});`, which made the behavior very strange. Anyway, thanks again for the earlier clarifications. Best wishes!