# How do we make use of `mouseover` and `mouseout` event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

As JQuery document says, I have converted many lines mouseover to mouseenter because it does not fire more than once.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

> **`mouseover`** fires when the pointer moves into the child element as well
>
> **`mouseenter`** fires only when the pointer moves into the bound element.

Even `hover` event works as mouseenter and mouseleave, not as mouseover and mouseout.

It makes me wonder why there is `mouseover` event if `mouseenter` can do it all.

For me, `mouseover` gets fired unpredictably when you move mouse around on an element. It seems really dependent on the depth of child elements.

Is there a good use-case of `mouseover` and `mouseout`, which needs to fire multiple times?

Comment: `mouseover` and `mouseout` are part of the official W3C standard and the other two are (useful) inventions of Microsoft. They might have emerged at the same time, which would explain why there are two ways now and both of them might be useful in certain situations. Now, I understand that you want to know *which* situations. I just wanted to give a brief overview of their origin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the mouseover and mouseenter events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)

Comment: @Bergi I do not think this question matches that duplicate because this specific question is asking for a use-case for `mouseover`/`mouseout` while already understanding the difference from `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`

Comment: @Bergi, I understand the difference, and am just curious of use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

That I know of, there is no use case for `mouseover`/`mouseout` at all.  The only reason they exist is because these events are triggered by browsers because [they are in the standard DOM event list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events).  `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are *not* standard events, but they are jQuery-specific constructs.

I suppose a use case would be if you wanted the event to trigger when moving the mouse over and out of the children of the element that the events are bound to.  I can't think of anything specific, but at least this functionality is available.  If only `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` existed, you wouldn't have a choice in the matter.

From http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js:

```
jQuery.each({
    mouseenter: "mouseover",
    mouseleave: "mouseout"
}, function( orig, fix ) {
    /* content snipped */
```

Speculation: the reason why the creators of jQuery created the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` non-standard events is because their behavior works as you would expect the `mouseover`/`mouseout` events to work (i.e. without regard for descendants).

Comment: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are from IE.

Comment: Do `enter`/`leave` bubble in jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

Because the event contains coordinates of cursor. 
So if you need to track mouse coordinates under the target, you have to use 'mouseover'

Comment: I thought that was `mousemove`