# Nested elements hover handle

Tags: jquery

All, I am stuck with a problem which deal with the nested element hover handler. It seems When the mouse enter the `child` div , the ancestors are also in `hover` state, Is there any ways trigger the `hoverout` event of ancestors ,when mouse enter the `child` element?

Below is what I trying to make it so far. please review it .

```
<style>
div
{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
}
</style>


  <script>
      $(function() {
           $('div').each(function(){
             var current = this;
             $(this).hover(function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();// doesn't work.
                console.log('Capture for hover in ' + current.tagName + '#'+ current.id +
                    ' target is ' + event.target.id); },
               function(event){
                  event.stopPropagation();
                  console.log('Capture for hover out' + current.tagName + '#'+ current.id +
                    ' target is ' + event.target.id); });

                            });
                        });
 </script>

 <body id="greatgrandpa">                        
        <div id="grandpa">
               <div id="parent">
                  <div id="child"/>
               </div>
        </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Just remove the asterix and run the function on the image? You're attaching event handlers inside a loop that iterates over ***all*** the elements on the page!

Comment: Hi, @adeneo, I just update the question to make it clearly . please review it .thanks.

Comment: I really don't get it, but you can set the mouseenter / leave functions to anything you'd like, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FXU65/) ??

Comment: Hi , @adeneo, just image this, what if we don't how many nested div element in body? maybe the child has nest element. I just demo a simple case . thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.hover()` method binds handlers for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

However, if you employ the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events, these events are trigger when the mouse moves in and out of elements AND it's descendants.

See http://jsfiddle.net/5yQY5/ for an alternative attempt of your example.

Comment: It is making me confused before I got your answer.Thanks ,

Answer (score 1):

Use mouseover and mouseout events instead

```
$(function() {
    $('div').on('mouseover', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).addClass('my-bg');
    }).on('mouseout', function(e){
        $(this).removeClass('my-bg');
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MTYSp/)

Note: There is no need to iterate through each div and then add the event handler for each of them, you can just call `$('div').hover(...)`, it will register `hover` handler for all divs

Comment: Hi , @Arun P Johny , could you please tell me the difference between `hoverin hoverout` and `mouseover mouseout`? thanks.

Comment: you can look at some posts like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events

Answer (score 1):

You need to find if target `DOM` is `child` or not.

**Example**

```
$(this).hover(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('div#child'))
    {
        // your child span is being hovered over
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    else if($(e.target).is('div#parent'))
    {
        // your parent element is being hovered over
    }
});
```

Comment: @Joe.wang always welcome...I just tried to answer according to your code so i thought why edit code give the solution that fits with current code..