# Reduce image size using jquery?

Tags: css, jquery-animate, jquery, jquery-effects

I need to reduce the `image size` using `jquery`(not the `div` size) , when I entered the `mouse` into the `div` which contains an `image`.

My `div` will be,

```
<div class="toolbarIcon" >
    <img width="40px" height="40px" src="toolbar/user_login.png"/><label class="toolbarLabel">Login</label>
</div>
```

`CSS` will be,

```
.toolbarIcon {
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #E6E6E6;

    width: 60px;
    float: left;
}
```

Also `jquery` will be,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#toolbar").corner("5px");
    $(".toolbarIcon").corner();

    $(".toolbarIcon").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#FFCC80");
    });
    $(".toolbarIcon").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#EBEBFF");
    });


    $(".toolbarIcon").mouseup(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#FFCC80");
    });
    $(".toolbarIcon").mousedown(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#E6B85C");

    });

});
```

The `design` from,

[image]

To ,

[image]

Note : The size of the image was changed.How can I achieve this using `Jquery` , When I entered the mouse ion the `div`.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: use `.attr()` when you mouse over your div or `.css()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just set the size of the image and the browser will scale it for you and I would recommend using the `.hover()` event which covers both mouse over and mouse leave:

```
$(".toolbarIcon").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#FFCC80");
    $(this).find("img").css({height: "30px", width: "30px"});
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","#EBEBFF");
    $(this).find("img").css({height: "40px", width: "40px"})
});
```

You could also use just CSS for this too:

```
.toolbarIcon:hover img {
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
}
```

Depending upon the exact effect you want, you may also want to tweak the padding below the image to keep it vertically centered when you hover.

Comment: +1 for you and accepted the answer.Works great.Exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 1):

CSS only:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/esicod/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
.toolbarIcon:hover img{
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  padding-bottom:5px; // compensate resize
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO WITH CSS3 ANIMATION](http://jsbin.com/esicod/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
.toolbarIcon img{
  padding-bottom:0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
          transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.toolbarIcon:hover img{
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$(".toolbarIcon").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find("img").css("width","30px").css("height","30px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseeneter` and `mouseleave`. see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)

```
$(".toolbarIcon").mouseeneter(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#FFCC80");
    $(this).find("img").height("30").width("30");
});
$(".toolbarIcon").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#EBEBFF");
    $(this).find("img").height("40").width("40");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work

$(document).ready(function(){

```
 $('.toolbarIcon img').css('width', '60px')
});
```

or you could give the img an id such img1

$(document).ready(function(){

```
 $('#img1').css('width', '60px')
});
```

I ahvent tested this but i think it should work