# On hover of child <ul> <li> element change styles of parent <ul><li> element

Tags: javascript, html, css

**no jquery please**

I have the following menu with class=menu-list, I want that on hover of nested/child ul li item, to change background color to white of parent li element

Code and working demo:

```css
   nav .menu-list{
        background: white;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 60px;
        padding: 12px 0;
        display: none;
        width: 68vw;
        height: 100vh;

    }

    nav .menu-list li{
        background: white;
        display: block;
        color: #000000;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        border-left: 24px white solid;
    }

    nav .menu-list li:hover{
        background: #eee;
        border-left: 24px #eee solid;
    }

    nav ul li:focus {
        background: white;
    }

    nav ul li:focus ul {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: -24px;
    }

    nav ul li ul li:hover  {
        background: white;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu-list" style="display: block;">
    <li tabindex="1" onclick="location.href='#/work'; dimScreen()">Work</li>
    <li tabindex="2" onclick="dimScreen()">About
      <ul>
        <li onclick="location.href='#/about/what-we-do'">What we do</li>
        <li onclick="location.href='#/about/how-we-work'">How we work</li>
        <li onclick="location.href='#/about/leadership'">Leadership</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Lame paint screenshot to explain better:
[image]

Comment: As a short rundown of what you can do, you want to bind a mouseover event on your child element. In that event, you want to find the parent, in some form of `var parent = evt.parentNode`, and then you can manipulate the style by `parent.style.background='some hex color'`

Comment: I wrote out a javascript solution for your reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for trying but I only needed to add this to make it work

```
  .menu-list li:hover {
        background: #eee;
    }

    .menu-list li:focus {
        background: white;
    }
```

Comment: Thats it because the child UL is still a part of its parent.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you [can't do this with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/1249829). CSS has no concept of what it's parent element is.

As for javascript, you can use mouse events. Here's [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/chwbuvum/6/):

```
var parentOn = function(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#9d7';
}
var parentOff = function(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#97a';
}

var children = document.querySelectorAll('.child');    
for (var x = 0; x < children.length; x ++) {
    children[x].addEventListener('mouseover', parentOn);
    children[x].addEventListener('mouseout', parentOff);
};
```

A few things to note:

- Any JavaScript DOM query will return an array of nodes, so you must iterate over them to avoid error. JQuery hides this nicely so it can be confusing.
- the mouseenter and mouseleave combination is subtley different from mouseover and mouseout, you can [find out more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)
- Working out how to use JavaScript to add and remove classes would be better than using inline styles. [This answer will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/1249829). You'll be able to re-use the styles and it'll be easier to maintain - I'd such creating a utility function to handle this, like JQuery's `addClass()`.
- Using named function variables is a bit clearer than anonymous functions, and more re-usable.

https://jsfiddle.net/chwbuvum/6/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure CSS solution

As Tony Leigh pointed out, you cannot do **exactly** what you asked using pure CSS, but you *can* make it **look** like you want.

The changed lines in the CSS are commented in the snippet, and the main change in the HTML is the addition of the span tag in the top-level list elements.

The main idea is that each top-level `li` remains white, while the enclosed `span` turns gray on hover. That way, hovering over a sub-list doesn't change color of the parent `li`.

**Code Snippet**

```css
    nav .menu-list{
        background: white;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 60px;
        padding: 12px 0;
        display: none;
        width: 68vw;
        height: 100vh;

    }

    nav .menu-list li{
        background: white;
        display: block;
        color: #000000;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        /* changed from border to background color
        border-left: 24px white solid;
        */
        padding-left:24px; /* added to put back the "border-left" area */
    }

    nav .menu-list li:hover{
        background: white; /*changed from #eee to white */
        /* changed from border to background color
        border-left: 24px #eee solid;
        */
    }

    /* start added blocks */
    nav .menu-list li span {
        width: 100%;
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        left:-24px;
        padding-left:24px;
    }

    nav .menu-list li span:hover{
        background: #eee;
    }
    /* end added blocks */

    nav ul li:focus {
        background: white;
    }

    nav ul li:focus ul {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: -24px;
    }

    nav .menu-list li ul li:hover  {
        background: #eee;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu-list" style="display: block;">
    <li tabindex="1" onclick="location.href='#/work'; dimScreen()"><span>Work</span></li>
    <li tabindex="2" onclick="dimScreen()"><span>About</span>
      <ul>
        <li onclick="location.href='#/about/what-we-do'">What we do</li>
        <li onclick="location.href='#/about/how-we-work'">How we work</li>
        <li onclick="location.href='#/about/leadership'">Leadership</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm Toni Leigh btw :-P

Comment: not quite sure how this works, it might be an idea to simplify the example?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code based solution:

**JS**

```
var listElements = document.getElementsByClassName('submenu');
for (var i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
    listElements[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(evt) {   
        evt.target.parentNode.style.background = "red";
    });
    listElements[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(evt) {   
        evt.target.parentNode.style.background = "black";
    });
}
```

**HTML CHANGE**

```
<ul class="menu-list" style="display: block;">
  <li tabindex="1" onclick="location.href='#/work'; dimScreen()">Work</li>
  <li tabindex="2" onclick="dimScreen()">About
    <ul class='submenu'>
      <li onclick="location.href='#/about/what-we-do'">What we do</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='#/about/how-we-work'">How we work</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='#/about/leadership'">Leadership</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, for each of your submenus you will have, I added an additional `submenu` class to differentiate between the main menu and submenu. When you leave each element, it will change the background of the parent to black. When you enter, it will change it to red, based on the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

What it does is find the parent node and then manipulate the styling of that element.