# Using the mouseover event to show tooltips leads to flickering tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used the `mouseover` event to show tooltips for my buttons due to I have a Single-page Web Application, where the total number of buttons changes dynamically.

A button is defined like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs mapButton" data-toggle="tooltip" title="message">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> 
       Map
</button>
```

And I show and hide the tooltips with the js below.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', function () {
    console.log("show tooltip");
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});

$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', function () {
    console.log("hide tooltip");
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', function () {
    console.log("hide tooltip");
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

Whenever I move with the mouse over a button you will find `show tooltip` and `hide tooltip` several times in the console/output during the mouse moves over the button. This leads sometimes to flickering tooltips. Why is this the case and how can I avoid this?

Comment: Maybe try and use `.mouseenter()` as an alternative - see http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!