# Mouseout and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When a user mouses over a div it should change to the color red, when they mouse out it should change back to transparent. When they click on the div, it should change to color red.

For some reason, the mouse out event listener is conflicting with the click event listener. Can someone help? When I click on the div, it doesn't change to red.

```
div$.on('mouseover', function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});

div$.on('mouseout', function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});

div$.on('click', function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Note, I have to apply a background image dynamically to each element, so using CSS classes to add the background image is out of the question (because I don't know it before hand).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zccj8dbj/2/ Its working for me.

Comment: Update your Complete CSS, JS, HTML to sort the Issue @Jasmin

Comment: I'm not sure how it should work. Are you willing to keep red color after clicking on the div even user fires mouseout event? Currently when user fires click event and then fires mouseout the div will be white instead of red.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `boolean` variable to confirm that the click has occurred and then only run the `mouseout` code if the variable is false like this:

```
var is_clicked = false;

div$.on('mouseover', function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});

div$.on('mouseout', function () {
  if(!is_clicked) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
  }
});

div$.on('click', function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  is_clicked = true;
});
```

Note:  For multiple div elements user multiple is_clicked variables

Comment: I have multiple div elements like that though

Comment: Ah right, well you could create an is_clicked variable for each div element then.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do a CSS implementation with `:hover`; just make sure to add a specifying class to each element you would like this effect on.

**1. `:hover` and jQuery**

```js
var div$ = $('.redHover'); // name the class whatever you like

div$.on('click', function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.redHover {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.redHover:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='redHover'></div>
<div class='redHover'></div>
<div class='redHover'></div>
```

**2. `:hover` and vanilla JS**

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.redHover');

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) { 
  els[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.redHover {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.redHover:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='redHover'></div>
<div class='redHover'></div>
<div class='redHover'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) insead of `mouseover` [see why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can go with would be the following notes:

1. To those elements with hover effect add a class like `hoverable`.
2. Hover effect is only applied to those elements having this class.

HTML:

```
<div class="hoverable"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hoverable:hover{
    background-color: red
}
```

JavaScript:

```
div$.on('click', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

In this way, you can simply decide whether an element should be hover-able or not by adding or removing `hoverable` class. Also hover effect is applied in CSS level not JavaScript, which is more acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you really want to change *picture* in the div, not just *background color* which is relatively easy. Try this:

```
<div class="hoverable">
<img src="myImg.jpg" />
</div>

//css
.hoverable img{visibility:hidden;}
.hoverable:hover img{visibility:visible;}
.clicked img{visibility:visible!important;}

//JS
$('.hoverable').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```