# Angular 2 mouseover event on div and childs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a span child in a div.

On my div I have a `mouseover` event, when I hover on the `span`, my event triggers.

Simple code:

```
<div (mouseover)="showOverlay($event, FooBar)" (mouseleave)="showOverlay($event, FooBar)">
    <span>{{ someDataHere }}</span>
</div>


 public showOverlay($event, op, element): void {
    op.toggle($event, element);
    $event.preventDefault();
}
```

What I want is to keep showing my overlay when on child, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps `mouseenter` `mouseleave` are a better fit in your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, you are right, thank you. If you post this as a answer I will accept it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` cover this use case better because entering a child doesn't `mouseleave` to fire, only leaving the outside border of the actual element makes it to fire.

See also [What is the difference between the mouseover and mouseenter events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)