# keep mouse over active if hovering over another overlapping element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, hover

I've got a DOM structure like the one below. These to elements are overlaping. On hover, video start to play. Unfortunately, when I hover over `.showsOnHover`, mouseover and mouseout repeatedly fire one after another making `.showsOnHover` blink and video stutter.

What should I do to instruct browser to treat hovering over `.showsOnHover` as one continuous hover?

.html

```
  <video (mouseover)="mouseover()" (mouseout)="mouseout()"></video>
  <div [hidden]="!hovering" class="showsOnHover"></div>
```

.ts

```
  mouseover(e){
    this.hovering = true;
    this.video.play();

  }
  mouseout(e){
    this.hovering = false;
    this.video.stop();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when `showsOnHover` is shown, it covers up the video, which makes it mouseout, so it hides the div, then the hover event triggers again, and it shows the div, and it just loops over and over very rapidly.

You essentially will want to do one of the following:

- Put the mouseover and mouseout events on both the video *and* the `showsOnHover` elements, perhaps do it on a containing parent div element. This way the mouseout event won't be triggered when it's shown; instead it will only trigger when you leave the larger containing element.
- Add `pointer-events: none;` to your `.showsOnHover` class in the CSS. This makes that div transparent to mouse events. However, this could cause issues if you wanted to run any click events off that button.
- Change `mouseover` to `mouseenter` as mentioned in [Ram's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47460599/1025702)

Comment: That `pointer-events: none;` just saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`

```
mouseenter(e){
    this.hovering = true;
    this.video.play();

  }
```

> [.mouseover()] can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For
>   instance, when the mouse pointer moves over the Inner element in this
>   example, a mouseover event will be sent to that, then trickle up to
>   Outer. This can trigger our bound mouseover handler at inopportune
>   times. See the discussion for .mouseenter() for a useful alternative.

Please see [What is the difference between the mouseover and mouseenter events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)

Answer (score 1):

create a parent div and fire the same event on that,

```
<div class="parentDiv" (mouseenter)="mouseover()" (mouseleave)="mouseout()">
  <video></video>
  <div [hidden]="!hovering" class="showsOnHover"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` instead of `(mouseover)` and `(mouseout)`