# React child preventing calling parent method

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My child is preventing calling parent method when onMouseOver occurs. To better understand problem I'm adding code snippet and what I want to achieve.

```
  renderDropdown(){
    let dropState = !this.state.dropdownActive;
    this.setState({dropdownActive: dropState})
  }

<li key={item.class} onMouseOver={this.renderDropdown} onMouseLeave={this.renderDropdown}>{this.state.dropdownActive ? <div className="toolbar-dropdown"></div> : null}<i className={`fas ${item.class}`}></i></li>
```

When I hover on li element everything works as expected but when hover appears on `<i>` element method is not called. So the `<i>` element is covering the `li` method. How to fix this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onMouseOver` event fires again when the pointer enters a child element, toggling your dropdown state. Using `onMouseEnter` instead might work for you, as it will NOT fire again when the mouse enters a child element.

[see this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)