# Mouseover for 1 second before triggering the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseover

I've written a simple bit of code that shows a div on a mouseover event. I'd like to mouseover the element for 1s before the event takes place. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? with a brief explanation if possible so I know for next time.

```
$('.NavSelect h2').mouseover(function() {
$('.NavGroup').hide();
$('#' + $(this).prop('id').replace('item','content')).show();
});
```

Comment: As an aside to the question, I'd suggest replacing the ugly `$('#' + $(this).prop('id').replace('item','content'))` logic with a DOM traversal method, such as `find()` - if possible.

Comment: Relevant, for the difference between the two (current) answers:  [what is the difference between mouseover and mouseenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)

Comment: Hey Rory, do you have any advice or reference information so I can look into making this more efficient =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, you need a `setTimeout`:

```
$('.NavSelect h2').mouseover(function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.NavGroup').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).prop('id').replace('item','content')).show();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Here, the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

#### Update

If you would clear the timeout on `mouseleave` I suggest you somethig like this:

```
let time = 0;
$('.NavSelect h2').mouseover(function() {
  time = setTimeout(() => {
    $('.NavGroup').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).prop('id').replace('item','content')).show();
  }, 1000);
}).mouseleave(() => { clearTimeout(time); });
```

Comment: This works great, quick question. How would I use clearTimeout to cancel on mouseleave?

Comment: @AnthonyWhitefield I update my answer

Comment: Thanks works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to keep this timeout in a `data` property and clear it on `mouseout`.

```
$('.NavSelect h2').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function () {
      $('.NavGroup').hide();
      $('#' + $(this).prop('id').replace('item','content')).show();
    }, 1000));
}).mouseleave(function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    alert('mouse left');
});
```

Comment: This way - it won't fire if you move your mouse out of the element before the second is up.